# What is a "Product Backlog Delta report" in Scrum?

Tags: scrum

I'm a student studying game development, While researching into Agile, I kept seeing the term "Product Backlog Delta report" Usually in articles pertaining to Scrum. 
Upon looking deeper into what that Artifact was I couldn't seem to find a concrete answer, many of my efforts ended up looping back into a standard Product Backlog or a Backlog Burndown.

So my question is, What exactly is a Delta report? and how does it differ from a standard Product Backlog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd never heard of this specific term, but after reading a few sites ([1](http://projectized.blogspot.com/2006_08_01_archive.html), [2](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/30585-product-backlog-delta-report/)) and an [excerpt from *Development of the enterprises’ competitiveness in the context of demographic challenges* provided by Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=quJ0AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA341&lpg=PA341&dq=%22product%20backlog%20delta%22&source=bl&ots=xoqWX90c2d&sig=9aCQyClhUZWixZQ_B-qBqrUsYAg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iX6pVLbrIpGGNtCGg-gN&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22product%20backlog%20delta%22&f=false) and using past experiences, it appears that a Product Backlog Delta Report simply shows the changes to the Product Backlog between sprints. Each story can be in different states (not done, in progress, done). The Product Owner can also reorder stories, remove stories, and add new stories, so it will show the number of stories that have changed. If you are using tools, you could even identify what stories were added, removed, deleted, or changed.